# spring security version in spring-boot-starter-security

Tags: spring, security

How do I find what version of spring security used in the spring-boot-starter-security in spring boot version 3.2.4?

It is very frustrating with all the outdated information out there in the web.  Even spring.io document samples that marked deprecated.

Your time is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it at [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security)